# How can we add custom icon in sitecore?

Tags: sitecore-client

We have to add our own icon in Sitecore so that we can assign those icons to our items.
what would be procured to add custom icons in Sitecore?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=add+custom+icon+theme+sitecore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create folder structure as follow with diffrent icon size -

- TypeFolderName

  - 16x16

    - FileName.png
  - 24x24

    - FileName.png
  - 32x32

    - FileName.png
  - 48x48

    - FileName.png
  - 128x128

    - FileName.png

Where FolderName will be you custom name of folder and file name will be the name of the file. all you need to create a transparent(most of time) image with diffrent size as show above.

After that create a zip archive of your folder and need to upload into **"/sitecore/shell/Themes/Standard/"** location of your website folder.

or you can modify existing folder and upload your icons there as well.

Thanks

Comment: FYI, this only generates an error for me so it may not be a solution for Sitecore 9.3